# What is wrong with the shortest path written by the Floyd algorithm?

Tags: c, data-structures, floyd-warshall

I use the Floyd algorithm to write the shortest path. The data are this graph, but the path[0][7] obtained is 5 instead of 4. Why?

[graph data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBpPH.png)

[D[][]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DUFr.png)

[path[][]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlEBA.png)

The path weights from 0 to 9 in D are not wrong, but path[0][7] is wrong

---

the Floyd algorithm：

```
bool Floyd( MGraph Graph, WeightType D[][MaxVertexNum], Vertex path[][MaxVertexNum] )
{
    //Initialize path[] and Distance
    for( int i = 0; i < Graph->Nv; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < Graph->Nv; j++ ){
            D[i][j] = Graph->G[i][j];
            path[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    //Floyd algorithm
    for( int k = 0; k < Graph->Nv; k++ ){
        for( int i = 0; i < Graph->Nv; i++ ){
            for( int j = 0; j < Graph->Nv; j++ ){
                if( D[i][k] + D[k][j] < D[i][j] ){
                    D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];

                    if( i == j && D[i][j] < 0 )
                        return false;                

                    path[i][j] = k;
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

Complete code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define MaxVertexNum 100   //Maximum of 100 vertices
#define INFINITY 65535      //Define infinity
typedef int Vertex;
typedef int WeightType;
typedef int DataType;


// Vertex
struct Gnode{
    int Nv;     //the number of vertex
    int Ne;     //the number of edge
    WeightType G[MaxVertexNum][MaxVertexNum];   //Adjacency matrix
    DataType Data[MaxVertexNum];    //Vertex data
};
typedef struct Gnode *MGraph;

// Edge
struct Enode{
    Vertex V1, V2;      //Directed edges <V1,V2>
    WeightType Weight;      //Weight
};
typedef struct Enode *Edge;

//  Initialize an edgeless graph with VertexNum vertices
MGraph CreatGraph( int VertexNum )
{
    Vertex V, W;
    MGraph Graph;

    Graph = (MGraph)malloc(sizeof(struct Gnode));
    Graph->Nv = VertexNum;
    Graph->Ne = 0; 
    for( V = 0; V < Graph->Nv; V++ ){
        for( W = 0; W < Graph->Nv; W++ ){
            Graph->G[V][W] = INFINITY;
        }
    }

    return Graph;
}

void InsertEdge( MGraph Graph, Edge E )
{
    Graph->G[E->V1][E->V2] = E->Weight;
    Graph->G[E->V2][E->V1] = E->Weight;
}

MGraph BuildGraph()
{
    MGraph Graph;
    Edge E;
    Vertex V;
    int Nv;

    //Initialize the Graph
    printf("Enter the number of vertices：");
    scanf("%d", &Nv);
    Graph = CreatGraph( Nv );
    

    //Input Edge
    printf("\nEnter the number of edges：");
    scanf("%d", &(Graph->Ne));
    if( Graph->Ne != 0 ){
        E = (Edge)malloc(sizeof(struct Enode));
        for( int i = 0; i < Graph->Ne; i++ ){
            scanf("%d %d %d", &E->V1, &E->V2, &E->Weight);
            InsertEdge( Graph, E );
        }
    }

    //vertex data
    printf("\nEnter vertex data：\n");
    for( V = 0; V < Graph->Nv; V++ ){
        scanf(" %d",&(Graph->Data[V]));
    }

    return Graph;
}

bool Floyd( MGraph Graph, WeightType D[][MaxVertexNum], Vertex path[][MaxVertexNum] )
{
    //Initialize path[] and Distance
    for( int i = 0; i < Graph->Nv; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < Graph->Nv; j++ ){
            D[i][j] = Graph->G[i][j];
            path[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    //Floyd algorithm
    for( int k = 0; k < Graph->Nv; k++ ){
        for( int i = 0; i < Graph->Nv; i++ ){
            for( int j = 0; j < Graph->Nv; j++ ){
                if( D[i][k] + D[k][j] < D[i][j] ){
                    D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];

                    if( i == j && D[i][j] < 0 )
                        return false;                

                    path[i][j] = k;
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    MGraph Graph;
    Graph = BuildGraph();

    printf("\nThis is the adjacency matrix：\n");
    for( int i = 0; i < Graph->Nv; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < Graph->Nv; j++ ){
            printf("%-8d", Graph->G[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Shortest path
    int D[MaxVertexNum][MaxVertexNum];
    int path[MaxVertexNum][MaxVertexNum];
    Floyd( Graph, D, path );

    Vertex V1, V2;
    printf("starting point：");
    scanf("%d", &V1);
    printf("End point：");
    scanf("%d", &V2);

    
    
    int v1, v2; 
    v1 = V1;
    v2 = V2;

    while( path[v1][v2] != -1 ){
        printf("%d<-", Graph->Data[path[v1][v2]] );
        v2 = path[v1][v2];
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Tested data:

```
10
17
0 1 2
0 3 5
1 2 5
1 3 2
2 4 8
2 5 4
3 5 4
3 6 2
4 5 2
4 7 5
5 6 3
5 7 9
5 8 6
6 8 7
7 8 3
7 9 4
8 9 8
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: sorry, the code has gone directly into the question, but the picture I don't know how to transform to the text.

Answer (score 0):

The `path[i][j] = k;` line in `Floyd` does not take account of the fact that the shortest path (so far) from `k` to `j` may be via an intermediate node. Changing the line to `path[i][j] = path[k][j] == -1 ? k : path[k][j];` fixes that.

I would also recommend setting the distances from a node to itself to 0. That can be done by changing the line `D[i][j] = Graph->G[i][j];` to `D[i][j] = i == j ? 0 : Graph->G[i][j];`.

Comment: Thank you, I know where the problem is and the problem has been solved.